# How to track another .git folder without submodules?

Tags: git

There is a lot of advice on how to use [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). This question is likely **not** about that.

#### Goal

I have a *parent project* in which I have code that relies on some other repository. So I `git clone` that dependency and include it in my code. This could be done with a submodule.

However, I now realize that the dependency needs some patches to work in my private usecase. I patch the code in the subfolder. Now I would like to somehow

- have version control for my patches
- have all the files in the same remote repository
- maintain git history of the dependency

The first point can be achieved by either...

- ... creating a second remote repository that only contains the forked dependency plus my patches, then including that as a submodule. This has the disadvantage that I need to set up multiple repositories.
- ... deleting the `.git` folder of the dependency and adding the files to my parent project. This has the disadvantage that git history of the original dependency is lost and merging in future upstream changes gets more annoying because it now requires pasting the files.

#### Question

How can I track the subfolder, including its `.git` folder?

It seems to me like that should be possible, after all they are just files too. I am imagining that I could then commit in the subfolder when i make patches to the dependency code and later commit that whole new state in the parent repository as one bigger change.

#### What I tried

The obvious way to attempt this is to simply add and commit the subfolder. However, gits warning says it will actually not do that:

```
 git add firewall/proxy.py/
warning: adding embedded git repository: 11_pelafina/firewall/proxy.py
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> 11_pelafina/firewall/proxy.py
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached 11_pelafina/firewall/proxy.py
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

#### Why not Submodules anyway?

Submodules would mean that I need to set up a remote repository for every subfolder that itself has a git history. That would get more chaotic on my github than I'd like.

I know that cloning/pulling would not need much more manual work. But the initial setup is enough work that I'm thinking there should be a simpler way.

Comment: While you could theoretically track the `.git` folder of some working copy, you really don't want to. Git periodically re-packs and re-compresses the objects in there, leading to large binary diffs that will blow up your parent repository and will be impossible to merge. I think "creating a second remote repository that only contains the forked dependency plus my patches, then including that as a submodule" is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Forget about submodules, use subtree
2. "Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem" - don't increase number of repos, increase number of branches in repo

Comment: That indeed sounds like what I want, thanks! Having a look

Comment: I have read up on it [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec) and it is indeed exactly what I was looking for. However it seems to be tricky to get a good overview. If you could add some common example commands (adding a subtree from a new remote, adding a subtree from an existing untracked clone in a subfolder, pulling changes from upstream, how to extract the changes possibly eventually PR), that would be great! Most of that seems to be covered [in the debian manpage too](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-man/git-subtree.1.en.html)